# Allow cognito AWS API actions to complete only when requested by specific lambdas

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I want all auth requests to go through my own lambdas, which in turn will make calls to AWS Cognito API. I do not want javascript browser to be able to perform any actions by calling Cognito API directly.

Is it possible to accomplish this?  For example could lambda trigger check for IAM identity of original lambda caller and reject requests based on policy?

Lambda Caller --> Cognito API --> Lambda Triggers.

Answer (score 0):

> For example could lambda trigger check for IAM identity of original
>   lambda caller and reject requests based on policy?

This is not possible since Lambda triggers are invoked by Cognito, not the original caller.

However, it is possible to customize authentication flow by using your own Lambda endpoints and AWS SDK.

For example, you can execute the user registration via Cognito AWS SDK running inside a lambda function and disable the browser JavaScript in performing this action. For more information about this, refer to [Examples: using the JavaScript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html).